# sequenceQueue option in Velocity.js not working

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

In the documentation from velocity.js it says that when sequenceQueue option is set to false, forces the associated call to run in parallel with the call that came before it.

If we have one element with an animation moving the the left, and another element with another animation to move downwards, both should happen at the same time, however they happen in sequence...

what im I missing ?  How can I make them both at the same time ?

http://codepen.io/julianshapiro/pen/xnGDC/

```
var $element1 = $("div").eq(0),
    $element2 = $("div").eq(1),
    $element3 = $("div").eq(2);

var mySequence = [
    { e: $element1, p: { translateX: "+=100" } },
    { e: $element2, p: { translateX: "+=100" }, options: { sequenceQueue: false } },
    { e: $element3, p: { translateY: "+=100" } }
  ];

$.Velocity.RunSequence(mySequence);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs, `sequenceQueue: false` syncs the call with the call before it in the sequence. So to make the 3rd call in sync with the 2nd you need to add `sequenceQueue: false` to the 3rd call as in [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdppWV).

Or in code:

```
var $element1 = $("div").eq(0),
$element2 = $("div").eq(1),
$element3 = $("div").eq(2);

var mySequence = [
    { e: $element1, p: { translateX: "+=100" } },
    { e: $element2, p: { translateX: "+=100" }, options: { sequenceQueue: false } },
    { e: $element3, p: { translateY: "+=100" }, options: { sequenceQueue: false } }
];

$.Velocity.RunSequence(mySequence);
```